# How to add multiple input textfield values into db using php

Tags: php, mysql

How to insert multiple textfields value into mysqldb?

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['save'])){

    foreach($_POST['color'] as $key => $value)
    {
    if($color!="")
    {
        $color = $value['code'];
        echo $color;
        $rgb = hex2rgba($color);
        $rgba = hex2rgba($color, 0.7);
        /*echo $rgba;
        echo $value['key'];
        echo $value['code'];
        echo $value['order_color'];*/
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_colors values('','$rgba','".$value['key']."','".$value['code']."','".$value['order_color']."')";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die("Bad Query==><br><br>$sql<br><br>".mysql_error());
     }
}
    ?>


     <form action="" method="post" name="recommend">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="color[][key]" class="email" style="width:450px;font-   size:15px;font-weight:bold;"></td>
    td><input type="text"  value="" name="color[][code]" class="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  value="" name="color[][order_color]" class="email"     style="width:50px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="color[][key]" class="email" style="width:450px;font-   size:15px;font-weight:bold;"></td>
    td><input type="text"  value="" name="color[][code]" class="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  value="" name="color[][order_color]" class="email"     style="width:50px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>

     <tr>
     <td colspan="5" align="center"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Add Color" /></td>
    </tr>
     </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. Can you tell us what problem you are facing?

Comment: is there any error you are getting?

Comment: when  echo $value['key']; only this field is added in db but others text field value not added so help me for that... other field take as blank field
no error

Comment: A little bit out of the topic, but **ALWAYS** escape user input **BEFORE** database insertion! Either by `mysql_real_escape_string()` or better - use `PDO` prepared statement!

Comment: is ther qoutes in your data when you insert in DB

Comment: and bro you also not close first If condition

Comment: i missed to add closing braces in question sry for that

Comment: Use this => $color = htmlentities($_POST['color'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

Comment: Where is `$color` coming from in the `if` condition?

Comment: after removing this $color condition ican't get value of key and order_color

Comment: Either you are not pasting the whole code here or am missing something, I don't see how it works with a variable which hasn't been set. Can you do a `var_dump($_POST);` and paste here?

Comment: better to show us complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  <?php
      if(isset($_POST['save'])){

    foreach($_POST['color'] as $key => $value)
    {

        $color = $value['code'];
        echo $color;
        $rgb = hex2rgba($color);
        $rgba = hex2rgba($color, 0.7);
        /*echo $rgba;
        echo $value['key'];
        echo $value['code'];
        echo $value['order_color'];*/
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_colors values('','$rgba','".$value['key']."','".$value['code']."','".$value['order_color']."')";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die("Bad Query==><br><br>$sql<br><br>".mysql_error());
     }
}
    ?>


     <form action="" method="post" name="recommend">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="color[1][key]" class="email" style="width:450px;font-   size:15px;font-weight:bold;"></td>
    td><input type="text"  value="" name="color[1][code]" class="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  value="" name="color[1][order_color]" class="email"     style="width:50px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="color[2][key]" class="email" style="width:450px;font-   size:15px;font-weight:bold;"></td>
    td><input type="text"  value="" name="color[2][code]" class="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  value="" name="color[2][order_color]" class="email"     style="width:50px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>

     <tr>
     <td colspan="5" align="center"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Add Color" /></td>
    </tr>
     </form>
```

}

Comment: What is this? If you need to add more code/information you can edit your question.

Comment: I found the one mistake at input text in my code and it's worked

Answer (score 1):

Row1, Row2, Row3 are your table rows you need to name them to your table row.

```
<?php

      if(isset($_POST['colorkey'])){
            $colorkey = $_POST['colorkey'];
                    $colorcode = $_POST['colorkcode'];
                    $colorcode = $_POST['colororder'];          



        $sql = ("INSERT INTO tbl_colors (Row1, Row2, Row3) VALUES ('$colorkey', '$colorcode', '$colorcode')");

}
    ?>


     <form action="" method="post" name="recommend">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="colorkey" class="email" style="width:450px;font-   size:15px;font-weight:bold;"></td>
    td><input type="text"  value="" name="colorcode" class="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  value="" name="colororder" class="email"     style="width:50px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="colorkey" class="email" style="width:450px;font-   size:15px;font-weight:bold;"></td>
    td><input type="text"  value="" name="colorcode" class="email"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  value="" name="colororder" class="email"     style="width:50px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>

     <tr>
     <td colspan="5" align="center"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Add Color" /></td>
    </tr>
     </form>
```

Comment: try edited post. I deleted the if statement. Just to check if it actually works